# NSMutableArray of NSString in CoreData(iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmutablearray

I have a class, which describe an object for parsing XML. This class contains NSStrings and NSMutableArrays of NSStrings.I want to store parsed data using CoreData.  How should I write CoreData model to store such objects if there is no such data type like NSMutableArray? Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two entities, I'll call them `Array` and `String`.  `Array` has one relationship, `strings`, which is a one-to-many relationship with the `String` entity.  The `String` entity then has one attribute, I'll call it `string` too, which actually is a string and contains the value you need.  This will allow you to store them as a set, if the order is important add another attribute to the `String` entity called `order` and make it a number.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt an array data type, but u can box the string in a core data object (lets call it A for the remainder of the post). Then in the object (B) which you want to have the array of string (that persists) in just make a to-many relationship with the object A which contains the string, then youll have a Set of string on the object B which you can turn into an array and do with what you like. hope that helps